# Accessibility services read all contentDescription of all buttons if the user tapped on its parent view

Tags: android

I don't understand some of things regarding to accessibility services and how they actually work with other applications, but let's focus on that problem.

I've this line of `ImageButtons` views inside relative layout (green rectangle), each button has its content description to make accessibility services able to read the description of these images.

The problem is when the user tap over the parent of these button and touch to explore feature is active, it starts say the content description of all these buttons at once:
[image]

Once the user tap on an empty space in the relative layout of these buttons, or even the root parent layout, the accessibility service read all content description form these buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem finally! I've to use `setAccessibilityDelegate` for all of these buttons/views and override `dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent` with just `return true;`, so now I'm handling this, not TalkBack or even any other accessibility services :)

---

More details about **AccessibilityDelegate** class, [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.AccessibilityDelegate.html).